# IIS SMTP remote domain smart host never sends

Tags: iis, smtp, smarthost

I'm not a novice but sure feel like one,

Using IIS SMTP, I'm unable to get the smart host for a remote domain to send email.  Instead it always wants to send it from the IIS server unless I turn on smart host for entire SMTP IIS server in the properties.   No matter what settings I put in the remote domain settings, it never uses those settings to send email.  I've tried it on 2 servers and 1 server was a fresh install with defaults.  Here is my configuration:

- Defined 1 local domain
- Defined 1 remote domain (mydomain.com)
- SMTP properties does not have smart host
  configured
- Configured remote domain
  to use smarthost [10.124.100.20]
- Disabled SMTP server from trying to
  send email directly in the properties
- Sending email to myself using from "test@mydomain.com"

The only way to have the email route to the other SMTP server using smarthost is to have all domains route to the same IP address by setting the overall smarthost setting in the SMTP properties dialog.  No matter what settings I put in the remote domain settings, it never uses those settings to send email.  Totally ingores them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old but I just ran into the same problem.  After adding your remote domains you need to start and stop the smtp server before it will actually route the emails using them.